# wp_term_relationships with term_taxonomy_id of 0 causing issues with backup

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

After bulk tagging posts via mysql, I may have inserted a bunch of rows into my `wp_term_relationships` table that have a `term_taxonomy_id` of 0. I believe this causing issues when i try to backup the database (the error is akin to "duplicate id for primary key")

Question: Is it safe for me to delete all rows from where `term_taxonomy_id = 0?` Am I correct in thinking that such an term does not exist thus is causing issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was in fact the issue and there is no need for any rows with a `term_taxonomy_id` of `0`. This will cause an error in the plugin "Wordpress Migrate DB Pro'

Good news is, this post got me the tumbleweed badge. Hope this helps someone down the road who made the same mistake I did.